# SQL get last purchase price of a product from weak purchase detail table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two date variables: @date1 and @date2. @date1 is always greater than @date2.

I have the following two tables:

```
+--------+
|purchase|
+--------+
|purch_id|
|date    |
+--------+

+-------------+
|purch_details|
+-------------+
|purch_id     |
|product_id   |
|product_price|
+-------------+
```

Table "purchase" stores the purchase date and an unique identifier (purch_id).

Purch_details is a weak table with no unique identifier. It contains the details of the puchase which include the product id (product_id), the price I paid for the product (product_price) and an identifier to the "puchase" table (purch_id).

With an SQL statement, in the date range @date1-@date2, I want to get the price of every product at which I last purchased.

In other words, I want the last price I agreed to purchase every product in table purch_details during the date range @date-@date2. The result must not contain product_id duplicates. Therefore, the outcome should be something like:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|product_id | product_price |purchase_date|
|00001      | $10.10        |2014-01-01   |
|00002      | $12.45        |2014-04-30   |
|00003      | $9.20         |2014-04-30   |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

(on 2014-01-01 I last purchased product 00001 at $10.10. On 2014-04-30 I last purchased product 00002 and 00003 at $12.24 and $9.20 respectively)

I tried the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    purch_details.purch_id,
    purch_details.purch_price,
    purchase.date
FROM 
    purchase
    INNER JOIN
    purch_details ON purchase.purch_id=purch_details.purch_id
WHERE 
    purchase.date>=@date1 AND purchase.date<=@date2
GROUP BY
    purch_details.purch_id,
    purch_details.purch_price,
    purchase.date
```

The problem with the above SQL is that it returns rows with duplicate product_id.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT purch_details.purch_id,
           purch_details.purch_price,
           purchase.date,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY purch_details.purch_id 
                                 ORDER BY purchase.date DESC) RN
    FROM purchase 
    INNER JOIN purch_details 
    ON purchase.purch_id=purch_details.purch_id
    WHERE purchase.date BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
)
SELECT purch_id,
       purch_price,
       [date]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: the SQL does not compile. It says Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'